# Customize styles of popup from parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m trying to open a new URL as a popup. That works.
Now I´m trying to customize the style etc. from the popup. That doesn´t work.
What´s going wrong?

Exception:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"

```
                <script>
                function startGaLandingpage(url) {
                    params = 'width=' + screen.width;
                    params += ', height=' + screen.height;
                    params += ', top=0, left=0'
                    params += ', fullscreen=yes';
                    var url = 'https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=en&pli=1#realtime/rt-overview/a29259688w55318706p63647373/'
                    landingpage = window.open(url, 'landingpage', params);
                    var landingpagescript = document.createElement('script');
                    landingpagescript.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js';
                    landingpagescript.type = 'text/javascript';
                    landingpage.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(landingpagescript);

                    var div = landingpage.document.getElementById('ID-navPanelContainer').style;
                    if (div)
                        void (div.display = (div.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none');
                    var div = landingpage.document.getElementById('ID-headerPanel').style;
                    if (div)
                        void (div.display = (div.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none');
                    var div = landingpage.document.getElementById('ID-overviewPanelTrafficSourceValueOrganicTable').style;
                    if (div)
                        void (div.display = (div.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none');
                    var div = landingpage.document.getElementById('ID-overviewPanelGeoComponent').style;
                    if (div)
                        void (div.display = (div.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none');
                    var div = landingpage.document.getElementById('ID-footerPanel').style;
                    if (div)
                        void (div.display = (div.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none');
                    var div = landingpage.document.getElementById('ID-navToggle').style;
                    if (div)
                        void (div.display = (div.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none');
                    var div = landingpage.document.getElementById('ID-overtimePanel').style;
                    if (div)
                        void (div.display = (div.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none');
                    var div = landingpage.document.getElementById('ID-contextDetailsPanel').style;
                    if (div)
                        void (div.display = (div.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none');
                    var div = landingpage.document.getElementById('ID-reportHeader').style;
                    if (div)
                        void (div.display = (div.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none');
                    var div = landingpage.document.getElementById('ID-realtimeReportFootnote').style;
                    if (div)
                        void (div.display = (div.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none');

                }

            </script>
```

Comment: Given the fact that you used the jQuery tag, why do you use `document.getElementById('ID-navPanelContainer')` instead of `$("#ID-navPanelContainer");` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are redeclaring landingpage:

```
landingpage = window.open(url, 'landingpage', params);
...
var landingpage = document.createElement('script');
```

In that case you cannot use the former one inside the same function any more. This might just be adding to the issue.

I suggest renaming the new variable which holds the script tag maybe to `landingpagescript`

```
var landingpagescript = document.createElement('script');
```

Answer (score 0):

`document` refers to the `document` of the current page, i.e. the main page. You need to refer to the `document` of the newly opened window:

```
var div = landingpage.document.getElementById(...).style;
```

I suppose that old jQuery is also meant to load to the pop-up, so you'll need the same reference when appending the `element1` too.

Also it's possible, that opening the pop-up will take some time. Hence it's better to put all stuff for pop-up to a separate function, and call that function within `setTimeout`, or rather from the pop-up itself just before closing `body` tag.

---

**EDIT**

`div` will be `undefined` if `#ID-navPanelContainer` doesn't exist. Checking a `style` of `undefined` just throws an error. Your checkings should be something like this:

```
var div = landingpage.document.getElementById('ID-navPanelContainer');
if (div) {
    void (div.style.display = (div.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none');
}
```

Comment: Hi Teemu, I have now tried to fix it with your suggestion. But I always get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined" on landingpage.document.getElementsByTagName('head'[0].appendChild(landingpage);

Comment: Please check kms' answer, also consider the last part of my answer, i.e. try to use a delay before executing code for pop-up.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now (see edited code), I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null" at position: "var div = landingpage.document.getElementById('ID-navPanelContainer').style;" Here is the code example I want to use [link]http://www.vilepickle.com/blog/2011/11/29/00129-hacking-realtime-google-analytics-tv-display#.URF0aVpmI5t   But I don´t want to use links and set the changes automatically after open the popup.

Comment: Umh... there's no `div` elements at all in the pop-up page, just a couple of links. It's not useful to check, if `undefined` has a `style`, it'll throw an error.